# Convert from For to do while in Java

Tags: java

```
 for (String item : someList) {
     System.out.println(item);
 }
```

As would be the equivalent using "do while"?

Thank's.

Comment: I would start by reading http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2

Comment: Make use of the Iterator (someList.iterator()) and use the iterator.hasNext() method to check, if you need do iterate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
List<String> someList = new ArrayList<>();
//put some values
for (String item : someList) {
     System.out.println(item);
}
```

The equivalent of the previous code is :

```
int i = 0;
do {
    System.out.println(someList.get(i));
    i++;
} while (i < someList.size());
```

**EDIT**

Or like @Bathsheba mention in comment you can use `hasNext()` like so :

```
//convert your List to Iterator
Iterator<String> itr = someList.iterator();
```

Then you can loop throw your itr like so :

```
do {
    System.out.println(itr.next());
} while (itr.hasNext());
```

**Note**

If you are not sure if your list or itr can be empty you should to check before you loop throw your list like @cybi mention in his answer.

```
if(!list.isEmpty()){
   //loop throw your list or iterator
}
```

Good luck.

Comment: Although for a linked list, you've just created an O(N * N) algorithm. The real equivalent uses `hasNext()` &c. on the iterator.

Comment: check now @Bathsheba is that what you mean?

Answer (score 3):

The for loop does not create any output, if the list is empty. So the equivalent do while loop is something like:

```
    if (!someList.isEmpty()) {
        Iterator<String> iterator = someList.iterator();
        do {
            System.out.println(iterator.next());
        } while (iterator.hasNext());
    }
```

If you do not check for an empty list before the do while loop, you get an `NoSuchElementException`.

Comment: i hoped you get the accepted  answer, thank you i mention your name in my answer you can check, thank you for the information

Comment: At least we have the best possible answer now. Thank you for your mention. :-)
BTW I think the check for not empty is mandatory for an equivalent loop.